# How to install PHP SQL Server drivers in Ubuntu 19?

Tags: php, 19.04, mssql, odbc

I have followed the instructions on the tutorial for installation on Linux, but unfortunately the Unix ODBC dependencies are not available in the repos for Ubuntu 19.04.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017

I've managed even to compile the drivers with PECL and loading into my PHP cli and Apache (but the question is not about Apache or LAMP stack, is about the PHP drivers), but keeps telling me about the ODBC driver.

*I'm not trying to install SQL Server itself, just the native and PDO drivers for PHP being able to connect to the database, which is managed by Azure. I'm not intereseted in a LAMP stack 'cause I don't need MySQL nor Apache, at this moment I'm trying to do Functional Automated Testing, and the deploy to production goes to an IIS Server.*

Comment: welcome to askUbuntu! have you seen this: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lamp-overview.html

Comment: the link you posted is instructions for general linux/osx install.. have you tried following the ubuntu guide here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017 ???

Comment: The link I posted includes instructions for Ubuntu, but the ODBC drivers are not available for Ubuntu 19.04. And the link you offer is about SQL Server, not the drivers for PHP, I'll try to clarify my question.

Answer (score 3):

There is another article within the Microsoft's documentation, called [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). I think the steps mentioned there are exactly what you are searching for.

For Ubuntu 19.04 they offer only **Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server**, here is the relevant part:

> This article explains how to install the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL
>   Server on Linux and macOS, as well as the optional Command-Line Tools
>   for SQL Server (bcp and sqlcmd) and the unixODBC Development Headers.
>
> **Important:** If you installed the v17 `msodbcsql` package that was briefly available, you should remove it before installing the
>   `msodbcsql17` package. This will avoid conflicts. The `msodbcsql17`
>   package can be installed side by side with the `msodbcsql` v13
>   package.
>
> **Ubuntu**
>
> ```bsh
> sudo su 
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
>
> #Ubuntu 19.04
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
>
> exit
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
> # optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
> sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
> echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
> echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
> source ~/.bashrc
> # optional: for unixODBC development headers
> sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
> ```
>
> Note
>
> - Driver version 17.2 or higher is required for Ubuntu 18.04 support.
> - Driver version 17.3 or higher is required for Ubuntu 18.10 support.